# After deploying the Visual studio workflow in SP2013 breaking instances of in progress workflows

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, solution-deployment, visual-studio-2013, farm-solution, workflow-manager

I have been working on developing visual studio workflows for SP2013. This workflow is associated with a document library. I have noticed that each time i deploy the workflow it is breaking the workflow instances of previously running in progress workflows. Any suggestions on how to avoid this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered in [Visual Studio declarative workflow version controlling and upgrade](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/144624/visual-studio-declarative-workflow-version-controlling-and-upgrade/156496#156496).

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)